# Network connectivity for docker containers on Ubuntu VM

Tags: networking, docker, ip

I have installed docker on a Ubuntu VM. Running Ubuntu docker containers. The IP address taken by these docker container in `172.17.*.* (eth0)`. With this IP I will not be able to ping/access the docker container from the outside.
Hence I am trying to assign an IP with my local network range. I followed the steps:

- create a new bridge network with your subnet and gateway for your ip block

  `$ docker network create --subnet 10.255.*.0/24 --gateway 10.255.*.254 ipstatic`
- run a ubuntu container with a specific ip in that block

  `$ docker run --rm -it --net ipstatic --ip 10.255.*.2 phusion/ubuntu`
- curl the ip from any other place (assuming this is a public ip block duh)

  `$ curl 10.255.*.2`

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.255.*.2  port 80: connection
>   refused

With this, even the host is unable to access the `10.255.*.*` network.The docker container takes the `IP 10.255.*.2`, but still unable to access from outside. I am newbie to Docker. My aim is to access the docker containers to-from my local network.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify [network_mode: "host"](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/network-mode) when you create your container. It will be available at the same IP as your host. You will however have to make sure that it doesn't try to listen to a port that's already in use.

eg:

```
version: "2"
services:
  myapp1:
    network_mode: "host"
    etc
```

However, it's good practice to treat the host as a fortress and limit the containers that are directly accessible by the outside world. Only keep nginx at a public face for instance and keep all the other containers in a private internal network. I just wrote another answer about this a [few minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39204670/1556338).

Comment: Thank you for the information.  If **--net=host** is used then the docker container will have same IP/network configuration as of the host. I am looking for launching multiple containers(different IP's) from the same host and access them from outside.

Comment: Then `--net=host` is not what you want. Simply run your containers inside the host on the default internal bridge network, and make them visible to the outside world using port forwarding. Eg `docker run --name myapp -p 8080:80 nginx`. Bring up a browser at address http://<host-ip>:8080 and nginx's default page will show up.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions.
By following the method mentioned in, https://eatpeppershothot.blogspot.in/2015/12/using-pipework-to-enable-communication.html 
I was able to communicate with the other devices on network from the container.
Please note, this worked only on Standalone Linux PC not on an VM image.