# how to reach another container from a dockerised nginx

Tags: nginx, docker

I have nginx in a docker container, and a nodejs webapp in another docker container.
The nodejs server is reachable from the host server on port 8080.

The nginx docker container is listening to port 80 (will do the certificate later, first this base must be working).

And now I want a subdomain to be forwarded to this 8080 nodejs app. lets say app1.example.com

From outside I can reach the app by the server ip (or hostname) and port 8080 but not on app1.example.com. And it does work on app1.example.com:8080 (I have opened up port 8080 on the host server).

I get a bad gateway nginx message when approaching the app1.example.com So I get in the first nginx container, but how do i get back to the host server to proxy pass it to the port 8080 of the host server (and not port 8080 of the nginx container). looking for the reverse EXPOSE syntax.

the main problem is, of course if I use the ip and port 127.0.0.1:8080 it will try on the nginx container....
So how do I let the nginx container route back to the host 127.0.0.1:8080?

I have tried 0.0.0.0 and defining an upstream, actually been googling a lot, and have tried a lot of configurations... but not yet found a working one....

**Edit**
Just found out, this command of docker might help:

```
sudo docker network inspect bridge
```

This shows the Ip address used inside the containers (in my case 172.17..0.2), but not sure this address stays the same every time the docker will restart... (e.g. server reboot)

**Edit**
Following alkaline answer I now have (but still not working):

my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "2"
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx_img
    build: ../docker-nginx-1/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - backbone
  nodejs:
    container_name: nodejs
    image: merites/docker-simple-node-server
    build: ../docker-simple-node-server/
    networks:
    - backbone
    expose: 
    - 8080
  networks:
    backbone:
      driver: bridge
```

and my nginx (skipped the include in the conf.d folder for simplicity):

worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

```
http {

  sendfile on;

  upstream upsrv {
      server nodejs:8080;
  }

  server {

    listen 80;
    server_name  app1.example.com;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://upsrv;
    }
    
  }
}
```

**edit 31-08-2016**

this might be the problem, the name is not backbone, but called after the folder started the service from:

```
sudo docker network ls
```

out puts:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                       DRIVER              SCOPE
1167c2b0ec31        bridge                     bridge              local               
d06ffaf26fe2        dockerservices1_backbone   bridge              local               
5e4ec13d790a        host                       host                local               
7d1f8c32f259        none                       null                local
```

**edit 01-09-2016**

It might be caused by the way I have my nginx docker container setup?

this is the docker file I used:

```
############################################################
# Dockerfile to build Nginx Installed Containers
# Based on Ubuntu
############################################################

# Set the base image to Ubuntu
FROM ubuntu

# File Author / Maintainer
MAINTAINER Maintaner Name

# Install Nginx

# Add application repository URL to the default sources
# RUN echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main     universe"     >> /etc/apt/sources.list

# Update the repository
RUN apt-get update

# Install necessary tools
RUN apt-get install -y nano wget dialog net-tools

# Download and Install Nginx
RUN apt-get install -y nginx  

# Remove the default Nginx configuration file
RUN rm -v /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Copy a configuration file from the current directory
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

# Append "daemon off;" to the beginning of the configuration
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 80

# Set the default command to execute
# when creating a new container
CMD service nginx start
```

**My final solution 1th sept. 2016**

I used this compose file now:

```
version: "2"
services:
    nginx:
      image: nginx
      container_name: nginx
      volumes:
        - ./nginx-configs:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      ports:
        - "80:80"
      networks:
        - backbone
    nodejs:
      container_name: nodejs
      image: merites/docker-simple-node-server
      build: ../docker-simple-node-server/
      networks:
        - backbone
      expose: 
        - 8080
networks:
  backbone:
    driver: bridge
```

In the project folder, from which you run docker-compose up -d, I added a folder named nginx-configs. This folder will 'override' all the files in the nginx container named /etc/nginx/conf.d

Therefor I copied the default.cfg from the nginx container before I added this volume mount. using the command:

docker exec -t -i container_name /bin/bash

and than cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

and added the same default.conf in the project folder with nginx configs.

Besides the default I added app1.conf with this content:

```
upstream upsrv1 {
    server nodejs:8080;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name  app1.example.com;
    
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://upsrv1;
    }
    
}
```

This way, I can easily add a second app... third and so on.

So the basics is working now.

Comment: The network name is not the problem. Within the compose file, `backbone` refers to the overlay network. When you list the networks, it will prefix the project name (the dir name by default) to each created container, network, volume.

Comment: Ok thanx. How do you ssh to the container when it is in background. Might be a problem with the firewall in the containers used (ubuntu as base)

Comment: You don't ssh into containers. You can ssh into the `host` by doing `docker-machine ssh <host-name>`

Comment: ah, i get it, big diff of course with virtual machines... but you can run a bash using: docker exec -t -i container_name /bin/bash

Comment: yes, that's how you can "log into" a running container.

Comment: when I try the same, my nginx throws an [emerg] error "host not found in upstream "express:3000""

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a best practice. Only expose port 80 outside of the host. The nodejs app can be in a private network only accessible through nginx.

```
version: "2"
services:
    nginx:
      ...
      ports:
        - "80:80"
      networks:
        - backbone
    nodejs:
      ...
      networks:
        - backbone
      expose: 
        - 8080

networks:
  backbone:
    driver: bridge
```

In your nginx.conf file, the upstream servers can be listed as `nodejs:8080`. The docker daemon will resolve it to the correct internal ip.

Comment: Thanx, so docker-compose is the way to go, untill now I just used the Dockerfile(newby with docker and nginx). Will try and give feedback.

Comment: Yes, better start with docker-compose right away. As soon as you have two services you're getting the benefits of `docker-compose up -d` knowing which one to update for instance.

Comment: ok, tried it, i get: ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', network 'backbone' must be a mapping not a string.

Comment: ok, a missing space between driver and bridge: "driver: bridge" in stead of "driver:bridge"

Comment: Corrected (missing space)

Comment: I still get the bad gateway.... I added my docker compose file and my nginx conf files. I also still have the sepeare Docker files in the folders per docker container.

Comment: Remove the `upstream upsrv {` section and simply use this in your proxy_pass line `proxy_pass http://nodejs:8080`

Comment: Sorry, no difference... nginx 502 bad gateway message

Comment: Can you see the default nginx page if you point your browser to http://<host-ip>:8081 after doing this `docker run --name nginx2 -p 8081:80 nginx` ?

Comment: Yes, I do see the default now.

Comment: You think it is caused by my nginx container setup? (i included the docker file i am using, see edit 1-9-2016)

Comment: You're not running nginx with the right params. Your last line should be `CMD exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'`. But instead of updating it, you should really start from the nginx image, not an ubuntu one. It will already have all the nginx stuff included and properly setup. https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/

Comment: Ok, i have it working now, thanks to all the help of Alkaline. I will add my final solution, but the credits go to Alkaline, so I'll accept this as the right anser.

Comment: I get error using this, `nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "service:3000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:3`